# Bootstrap Modal tab first set active when close

Tags: javascript, html

When close bootstrap modal with 2 tabs the focus not return to the first tab always stays in the second tab

The problem is what

HTML, BLADE:

```
<a class="Ver" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Ver" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DvModalOperacionesMensajes">

<div class="modal fade" name="DvModalOperacionesMensajes" id="DvModalOperacionesMensajes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" name="H4ModalOperacionesMensajes"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#Ver" data-toggle="tab">Ver Mensaje</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Responder" name="AResponder" data-toggle="tab">Responder Mensaje</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="Ver">
                        Content 1

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Responder">
                        Content 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {!! Form::button("<i class='fa fa-remove fa-lg'></i> Cerrar", array("class" => "btn btn-default", "data-dismiss" => "modal")) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('div[name=DvModalOperacionesMensajes]').on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        InicializarCampos ();
        $('#DvModalOperacionesMensajes a:first').tab('show');
    });
```